# Forge - progressbar when using Aggregatedview

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to avoid the flashing of the progressbar when using AggregatedView and loading multiple models? I would like the progress bar to follow the global loading of the models.

Comment: please share the screenshot

Comment: it's the only Forge progress bar, the one that animates. When using multiple models, it jumps back and forth and it doesn't seem to follow a global value

Answer (score 0):

progress bar is a div container, not part of the viewer canvas. Its class name is 'progressfg', you can try manipulating its CSS. Not clear on the global loading of the models.